# Remote Database connection parameters code

Tags: asp.net, database, database-connection

I need to write a code that set up a connection to remote database over the internet, the code should be able to connect to any database independent on the server type.
What are the parameters I need to take from the user as inputs?
It'll be much appreciated if someone can give me the connection code in ASP.net?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

static URL of the database server,
User name,
Password,
Database name.